# Electron TypeError: Cannot read property 'normalizePath' of undefined

Tags: javascript, node.js, electron, typeerror

I'm building a simple application using Electron. I want to access Node.js `fs` and `path` but I can't figure out the right way to do it.

Here is the error:

> Exception has occurred: TypeError
>
> TypeError: Cannot read property 'normalizePath' of undefined

Here is a sample of the code I'm using, in the `main` process (not the `renderer`):

```js
const { path } = require("path");

const something = () => {
  // Normalize the folder path
  path.normalize("path/to/file.txt");
});

something();
```

I've read this thread (https://github.com/electron/electron/issues/7300#issuecomment-248773783) and tried to apply the fix but it did not helped and threw another error, so I'm back to start.

I'd be glad if you had some hints on how to get it working.

Comment: try just `path.normalize()`: https://nodejs.org/api/path.html#path_path_normalize_path

Comment: Oh. You're right @Gavin, my bad. I've mistyped my question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Path is default export from path module, so your require

```
const { path } = require("path");
```

should be

```
const path = require('path');
```

and it should be [`path.normalize()`](https://nodejs.org/api/path.html#path_path_normalize_path)

Comment: @SergiiVorobei this what the answer is saying

Comment: Sorry, I've mistyped the code in my answer, it was indeed `path.normalize()`

Comment: @Gaspacchio it's okay,  did you tried the suggested thing  ?  did changing to `const path = require("path")` worked for you ?

Comment: Waow, I never would have suspected that this could be the problem. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You should use node.js path module:

```
const path = require('path');

const something = () => {
// Normalize the folder path
  return path.normalize("path/to/file.txt");
});

console.log(something());
```

Comment: I don't understand your answer, where is the difference?

Comment: the difference is that you are trying to destructure the object which is returned from the `require('path')` call and get 'path' property from it, which is a wrong thing to do. So `const path = require('path') and const { path } = require('path')` are not the same thing.